# How to print data from table which has same data in a column using sqlite3 in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to get or print the data from the table, in which one column has same data.

I will be more clear.

This is the table

```
Name      Team      Task       Status
John      A         shgdjd     Awaiting
Sam       B         jhdhfc     Awaiting
Jerry     C         hscdusc    Accepted
Roy       A         jdshdjc    Awaiting
```

I need to print only these as they have the status= "Awaiting"

```
Name: John Team: A Task:shgdjd
Name: Sam  Team: B Task:jhdhfc
Name: Roy  Team: C Task: hscdusc
```

So I am writing as below,

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("practice.db")
c = conn.cursor()
requests = c.execute("SELECT Name, Team, Task, Status from Request_Info")
for column in requests:
    if "Status" == "Awaiting":
         print "Name: ", column[0]
         print "Team: ",column[1]
         print "Task: ", column[2]
```

But, I am not getting any output. Could anyone please help me to get from this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via dictionary cursor.

You need to access the dictionary key like this

`column["Status"]`

So your code would look like this.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("practice.db")
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
c = conn.cursor()
requests = c.execute("SELECT Name, Team, Task, Status from Request_Info")
for column in requests:
    if column["Status"] == "Awaiting":
         print "Name: ", column[0]
         print "Team: ",column[1]
         print "Task: ", column[2]
```

Or I believe you can do it if you called `column[3]`

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("practice.db")
c = conn.cursor()
requests = c.execute("SELECT Name, Team, Task, Status from Request_Info")
for column in requests:
    if column[3] == "Awaiting":
         print "Name: ", column[0]
         print "Team: ",column[1]
         print "Task: ", column[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter and call only the records which have the status as "Awaiting"

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("practice.db")
c = conn.cursor()
requests = c.execute("SELECT Name, Team, Task from Request_Info WHERE Status = 'Awaiting'")
for column in requests:
    print "Name: ", column[0]
    print "Team: ",column[1]
    print "Task: ", column[2]
```

This way you don't have to check the status of each record inside the for loop